# Array with Strings as index

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am supposed to store and keep track of a lots of counters (multiple counters for each meter, there are multiple meters spitting readings).

Is it OK to use one HashMap for each type of counter, so that the key becomes the meter id and  value becomes the counter. In this case I will have as many HashMaps as type of counters.

Or shall I use something like a HashMap of a HashMap.

And is there any way I can simply use Arrays for such a use case. For that I would need to replace/map Array index to meterid.  Not sure if that is possible at all, but it will be much efficient if I am not wrong as HashMap uses Array itself so Array got to be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not implement a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`. That way, you can map a `String` value, you're meter, to a lot of values, your counter values.

**Example**

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> counterMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

values.add("Counter reading 1");
values.add("Counter reading 2");
values.add("Counter reading 3");

counterMap.put("Meter", values);
```

Now to get all of those readings, you can simply write:

```
List<String> meterCounters = counterMap.get("Meter");
// Contains "Counter reading 1", "Counter reading 2", "Counter reading 3".
```